# Overwrite Built-In Function input() to submit with SPACEBAR

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, linux, cython

Python's [**input()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) method prompts the user to enter a string in the terminal. They submit the string with **ENTER** key.

I would like to overwrite the [**input()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) method and replace the key from **ENTER** to **SPACEBAR**.

How do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Nope.  You would have to write your own function.  The methods for doing so are different on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Why do you have to redefine `input()`? Write your own function that does this, and use that instead.

Comment: Note that the newline processing is being done by the operating system, not Python. You will need to use OS-specific functions to change the terminal mode so you can process the input by character instead of by line. And you'll need to implement all your own input editing.

Comment: A better option is to use the [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) module. It allows you to customize key bindings, so you can configure space to submit the line.

Comment: @Barmar I believe he means he wants a function _similar_ to `input()`, but with the submission keybind being SPACEBAR rather than ENTER

Comment: @stackoverflowuser I understand what he wants. But since `input()` presumably just calls `fgets()` internally, it's totally dependent on the way the terminal driver works.

Comment: Please don't tag this question in more than one programming language... If you're talking about a python function, then _only_ tag it python. Note that it is however okay to tag with `python-3.x`, `cython`, etc. as similar technologies that relate to your question

Comment: @Barmar Yes but couldn't he code something in cpython to check OS via `#if defined(_WIN32)`, `#else`, etc.?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser Maybe, but it will be extremely complicated. As I said, he'll need to put the terminal in raw mode and implement all the input editing himself.

Comment: @Barmar I believe coding a custom input function in python to handle each character independently, then trigger submission with SPACEBAR as intended... See my answer for more information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232314/discussion-between-stackoverflowuser-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is achievable in vanilla python, however you could try using the curses library to disable input buffering (waiting for ENTER) and read input character by character. After doing this, you could easily implement a spacebar submission system via reading characters into a string and, when SPACEBAR is pressed, registering that string to a central location.

Comment: You'll also need to implement Backspace, arrow keys, etc.

Comment: @Barmar Not quite... When input buffering is disabled, the only difference is that `stdin` is flushed after every character, rather than on `\n`. Backspace and arrow keys produce ascii escape sequences that the terminal itself handles

Comment: If you're reading character by character, and the user types an arrow key, you'll receive the escape sequence. You'll need to translate this to the appropriate cursor movement operations in curses.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not quite familiar with ascii escape sequences or the python programming language, but this still begs the question; can you _do_ this? How could you handle those specific escape sequences without recoding the terminal input system specifically for your program (arrow keys and backspace coordinated with overwriting the string and calling `move(x - 1, y)`)?

Comment: I've never done any curses programming, I think it has some higher level functions to assist with this. But my suggestion to use `GNU readline` seems much simpler.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. I'll leave this answer up for anyone who finds it useful...